Google Sheets - different running totals in the same column
I have this sheet with 4 columns: date | name | quantity | running totals
In the "name column" are listed different items that are added or subtracted every few days and the respective quantity in the adjacent column.
I need to automate the "running totals column" so that it displays the total count of the specific item.
See screenshot for better understanding
Table screenshot
I tried =ArrayFormula(if(C2:C="";;scan(0;C2:C;lambda(a;v;(a+v))))) but sums everything together and i can't figure out how to put some sort of filter in it.
This =ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="banana"; SUMIF(IF(B2:B="banana"; ROW(B2:B); ROWS(B:B)+1); "<="&ROW(B2:B); C2:C);)) works but only by inserting "name" in the function which isn't useful and becomes incredibly slow on large datasets.
Please feel free to experiment on this shared sheet and thanks to anyone how can help.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nfVdrxNAgKc7R70LIn4Sajix6WesHnl1hc9u3AttwuI/edit?usp=sharing


You may try:
=map(B3:B;C3:C;lambda(Σ;Λ;if(Σ="";;sumif(B3:Σ;Σ;C3:Λ))))



Thank you so much! It works exactly how i wanted.
